# How to change string after changing language in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have such a function in my component .ts file:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
        console.log("language changed");
        this.paginator._intl.itemsPerPageLabel = this.translate.instant("CUSTOMER.MESSAGES_LIST_TABLE.PAGINATOR");
    });
}
```

On my website I've got toolbar for changing language and I've got a paginator with string "Items per page" at the bottom of website.

I've done all imports etc in my component file (TranslateService, LangChangeEvent). The onLangChange event works fine - "language changed" is shown in the console when I switch to other language.

But what doesn't work is "Items per page" in paginator". When I change language of my website it doesn't take affect.

I keep my translations in .json file (CUSTOMER.MESSAGES_LIST_TABLE.PAGINATOR).

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: are you using ngx-translate?

Comment: Yes, TranslateService and LangChangeEvent are imported from @ngx-translate/core

Comment: Can you post how did you translate CUSTOMER.MESSAGES_LIST_TABLE.PAGINATOR? Like this ? `{{"CUSTOMER.MESSAGES_LIST_TABLE.PAGINATOR" | translate}}`

Comment: No, I don't use  translation via pipe in HTML template. I've got translations defined in .json files and I use translate.instant

Answer (score 0):

```
  this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
      this.paginator._intl.itemsPerPageLabel = this.translate.instant("itemsPerPageLabel");

      //JUST ADD LINE BELOW, you need to update your paginator

      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

    });
  }
```